# Stop windows 8 applications from stealing focus

Tags: windows-8

I hate it when I'm waiting for an install to finish so I'm typing an email and it pops up and says "Do you want to restart now" right as I hit enter!

Is there any way to avoid this?  I've seen the tweak-ui thread, please don't close this as a duplicate pointing to that...

Comment: What prevent an installer from attempting to finish the installation? Unlikely unless you modfy the installer in question.  This isn't unique to Windows 8.

Comment: Yes, but there are solutions like Tweak-UI for other versions of windows.  And no, don't "prevent an installer from attempting to finish..." just prevent ANY notifications/popups/new windows from stealing focus.